# how to find all subwords of a string

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to understand how to find all possible combination(sub strings) of a given string. i thought about an algorithm which works and its basically like this:

Example: `"abc"`

1. Remove none - add `"abc"` to output
2. Remove first char (`"bc"`) - add to output, then second (`"ac"`) - add to output, then remove third (`"ab"`) - add to output.
3. Remove 2 chars (`"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`) and add to output

Now, I don't know how I'm going to write this so I am asking for a little help, nothing advanced as this is my hw and I want to learn and do it myself. More specifically I would like to know how to remove a char from the middle without changing the input.

Also, `"cb"` isn't a sub-word for me beacuse all subwords needes to be in the smae order they are showed in the original string.

Comment: Have you tried anything? With no effort shown so far, people are going to think you're just asking us to do your homework for you. StackOverflow is for **specific, code-related** questions. If you need general guidance on how to get started or clarification, see your professor/TA/teacher.

Comment: So if you had "abcd", you would want to get: a, b, c, d, bcd, acd, abd, abc, cd, ad, cd?

Comment: Yes i tried,i made a function that can remove letters by index and i thought how can i do the code in recursive call but i cant think of anything

Comment: Show your code then and detail what specifically is the issue with it.

Comment: You need to keep track of the # of chars there are, how many you're up to removing, where you are in the String and if the current position + how much you need to remove <= total length

Comment: you would have abcd,abc,abd,acd,bcd,ab,ac,ad,cd,bc,a,b,c,d and the empty string

Comment: @DavidBarishav: is the empty string also considered to be a substring?

Comment: yes it is considered a substring

Comment: this is a job for recursion. The substrings of `abc` is all the substrings of `bc` with and without a leading `a`. Same principle goes for `bc`, until the input is the empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this: You must find all the subwords that start with the first character, then with the second character, then with the third... and so on.

This can be written as a recursive algorithm, taking two arguments:

1. The "prefix"
2. The subword *after* the prefix

In the first iteration, the prefix will be an empty string, and you will fill it gradually with subwords and print one character.

The easiest way I can show you how this works is a code snippet:

```
public void printAllSubWords(String prefix, String subword) {
    for(int i = 0; i < subword.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(prefix + subword.charAt(i));
        printAllSubWords(prefix + subword.charAt(i), 
                         subword.substring(i + 1, subword.length()));
    }
}
```

How this works?

First, consider a string of length 2:

```
printAllSubWords("", "ab");
```

The execution sequence would be like this:

When `i = 0`:

- `System.out.println(prefix + subword.charAt(i));` will be evaluated like this:

  `System.out.println("" + "ab".charAt(0));` and will print `a`
- Then the call

  `printAllSubWords(prefix + subword.charAt(i), subword.substring(i + 1, subword.length()));` will be

  `printAllSubWords("" + 'a', "ab".substring(0 + 1, "ab".length()));`, which is:

  `printAllSubWords("a", "b");`
- Now, in this second pass, `System.out.println(prefix + subword.charAt(i));` will be evaluated like this:

  `System.out.println("a" + "b".charAt(0));` and will print `ab`
- Then, still in this second pass, `printAllSubWords(prefix + subword.charAt(i), subword.substring(i + 1, subword.length()));` will be

  `printAllSubWords("a" + 'b', "b".substring(0 + 1, "ab".length()));`, which is:

  `printAllSubWords("ab", "");`
- In the third pass, the `for` will not be executed, because the length of this new subword (`""`) is zero, so we return to the top-most call.

When `i = 1`:

- `System.out.println(prefix + subword.charAt(i));` will be evaluated like this:

  `System.out.println("" + "ab".charAt(1));` and will print `b`
- Then the call

  `printAllSubWords(prefix + subword.charAt(i), subword.substring(i + 1, subword.length()));` will be

  `printAllSubWords("" + 'b', "b".substring(0 + 1, "ab".length()));`, which is:

  `printAllSubWords("b", "");`
- In this new second pass, the `for` will not be executed, because the length of this new subword (`""`) is zero, so we return to the top-most call, which will end the execution.

Try to write the execution sequence for a three or four character word, and see what happens.

Hope this helps.

---

In your comment you say that you want to store the subwords in an array (and you're very specific: You don't want a list, but a simple array). That is possible, but it has some problems.

- You need to know *beforehand* how many entries you'll need for the array. Since arrays cannot be resized, you need to do that calculation before the thing starts.

I'd honestly would recommend you use a `List` (specifically, an `ArrayList`), but let's see if it's possible to calculate the length of the array.

```
Word lenght | Number of subwords
------------+-------------------
  1         |   1
  2         |   3
  3         |   7
  4         |   15
  5         |   31
```

[This question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171803/number-of-sub-sequences-in-a-given-sequence) gave me the hint on how many subwords there are be in a word of length `n`. I leave to you figure it out (hint: The last part of the answer holds the key for the number of subsequences, but it includes the *empty* subsequence).

One possible solution is this:

1. Create an integer static variable (a class variable) that holds the iteration you're executing. That number starts in zero and increases in one unit every time you print/store the subword
2. In the same class, write a method that creates an array of the appropriate size.
3. Modify the above method to receive, additionally to the prefix and the subword, this newly created array.
4. Substitute that `System.out.println()` stuff with a sentence that stores the generated subword into the array, using the static variable I mentioned in step 1 as index.
5. When you call the function again, be sure to pass also the array.

I'll come back in a couple of hours to write the code example, but I'd like you to try first to solve it yourself (also, that link above gave me an idea for another approach to solve this problem that doesn't require recursion, and I'll include it in my future edit)

---

The solution I told you about previously is something like this:

```
public class SubwordPrinter2
{
    private static int index;
    private static void generateSubwords(String prefix, String subword, String[] arr) {
        String s;
        for(int i = 0; i < subword.length(); i++) {
            s = prefix + subword.charAt(i);
            arr[index] = s;
            index++;
            generateSubwords(prefix + subword.charAt(i),
                                subword.substring(i + 1, subword.length()),
                                arr);
        }
    }

    public static void generateAllSubwords(String word) {
        index = 0;
        String[] subwords = new String[(int)Math.pow(2, word.length()) - 1];
        generateSubwords("", word, subwords);
        for(String s : subwords) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Another solution without recursion**

Since order matters, you can create a sequence of binary flags that tell you wether a character must be included in the subword or not. Something like this:

```
String: abc
Flags:  001
        010
        011
        100
        101
        110
        111
```

Those are *binary* strings. So the algorithm would be:

- For `i` between `1` and the `(2^n) - 1` (where `n` is the length of the word)

  1. Create a binary string, *left padded with zeros* with the same length of the word.
  2. For each `1` in the binary string, print/store the matching character.

The code:

```
public void createSubwords(String word) {
    // As you can see, your array must have (2^n) - 1 entries
    String[] subwords = new String[(int)Math.pow(2, word.length()) - 1];
    String bin;
    String fmt;
    String subword;
    for(int i = 1; i < Math.pow(2, word.length()); i++) {
        // fmt will be used to format the binary string so it is
        // left padded with zeros
        fmt = "%0" + word.length() + "d";
        // bin is the binary string
        bin = String.format(fmt, Long.parseLong(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));
        // Initialize the subword
        subword = "";
        // For each '1' in the binary string, add the matching character
        // to the subword
        for(int j = 0; j < bin.length(); j++) {
            if(bin.charAt(j) == '1')
                subword = subword + word.charAt(j);
        }
        // Store it in the array
        subwords[i - 1] = subword;
    }
    // Print each subword
    for(String s : subwords) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot!I got it now! But I have one more question, how can you make this not print but stored in a string[]? Not a list of some sort just an array?

Comment: @DavidBarishav Happy to learn. By the way, if you find this answer useful, up-vote it and/or accept it. As for your question, let me edit my post to answer it

Comment: @DavidBarishav I've included some hints for your new question. Please try to solve this yourself with those hints. I'll come back later to edit the answer and include the code... and another idea I have to solve the original issue (that doesn't require recursion).

Comment: @DavidBarishav Check my updated answer: It has the solution to store the subwords in an array (using the recursive approach) and a new solution that does not use recursion

Comment: Isn't the base case is for the empty string?that it will return "" as one of the substings so it would be 2^n where n is the number of letter?

Comment: @Pure_eyes yes... technically... but I think the OP wants only non-empty sequences

Comment: @Barranka: euh, pure_eyes is the OP. That's why is highlighted in lightblue ;).

Comment: @CommuSoft Oops! Sorry (that's why I shouldn't be doing more than one thing at a time :$ )

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this in a `Iterator<T>`, this enables lazy generation of the content.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SubstringIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    String s;
    BigInteger cur = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger max;

    public SubstringIterator(String s) {
        this.s = s;
        max = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(s.length()).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cur.compareTo(max) < 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        cur = cur.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0x00; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(cur.testBit(i)) {
                sb.append(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This is not a collection iterator");
    }



}
```

The code works as follows: you need to declare a bitarray: an array with an arbitrary numbers of bits. Now here we use `BigInteger` because that's quite convenient, but you can use any equivalent datastructure.

The bitarray maintains a list of bits. When the *i*-th bit is `1`, that means that the corresponding character should be in the string to generate, so if the string is `foobar` and the state is `011011`, the the result will be:

```
foobar
011011
 oo ar
```

Thus `ooar`. The procedure to generate a String based on the bitarray is given by:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0x00; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if(cur.testBit(i)) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Now the only missing thing is iterating over the set of bitarrays with that length. For that, the methods provided by `BigInteger` are useful. This will do a binary increment. You could however for instance use a [*Gray counter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Gray_code_counters_and_arithmetic). In that case, the order of the output will be a bit different but that's not the main issue.

So what we so is we set `current` to represent the state. Initially the state is `00000...000`, thus the empty string. But we don't need to emit that state.

In the `hasNext` method, we check if the `Iterator<T>` has already reached the end of the possibilities. This is when the state is `11111....111`. We thus store the maximum in `max`, which is *n* times `1` with `n` the length of the string.

Finally the `next` method only has to increment the state and calculate the result.

Now you can of course generate an array with the results. But in general an `Iterator<T>` is better. An iterator doesn't store all values explicitly. So the memory usage is (nearly) constant whereas an array would result in an exponential memory usage.

Furthermore it can save CPU usage, simply because one does not always need to calculate all values. Say you are looking whether `foo` is a member, you can cut off search from the moment `"foo"` is generated whereas first constructing the entire array can be more expensive.

See online demo [**here**](http://ideone.com/wfPQgj).

In case the empty string is also considered to be a substring replace:

```
BigInteger cur = BigInteger.ZERO;
```

By

```
BigInteger cur = BigInteger.ONE.negate();
```

Comment: outright give him a solution?  `nothing advanced as this is my hw and I want to learn and do it myself`

Comment: @DoubleDouble: well give me a minute to explain the solution.

Comment: @DoubleDouble: better?

Comment: It's a nice solution and you explain it very well, +1 from me. I'm still not sure that counts as letting him "do it himself", I doubt he could apply this to a different but similar problem, but at least he has the information he needs to explain it if his teacher questions him about it.

Comment: Although this is a very nice answer, I think it defeats the purpose of teaching the basics of Java (I am under the impression that the OP is a beginner, and would like a beginner's answer).

Comment: @Barranka: well it's not necessarily *the* answer. But answers are not meant only for the initial OP. Furthermore recursion is also a bit advanced. Your answer is indeed easier to understand I guess. But there is nothing wrong with a "more advanced" construct that can be reused by others I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a recursive function.  It would look something like this

**this is not intended to be compilable java code.  It is only outlining an algorithm**

```
List<String> GetSubwords(String str)
{
    if(str.length == 1)
        return str; 

    List<String> result = new List<String>();
    FirstChar = str[0];

    // the portion of the string after the first character
    var smallString = str.Substring(1, str.length-1);
    List<String> smallerSubWords = GetSubwords(smallString);

    result.add(FirstChar.ToString())
    foreach(subword in smallerSubwords)
    {
        result.add(subword);
        result.add(firstChar + subword);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

This essentially takes a string, say "ABCD", removes the "A", and then gets a list of all of the subwords of "BCD", and returns the list of those, in addition to the list of those with the `'A'` tacked on the front

Comment: I am dont know list ,so if you can explain it ?

Comment: @DavidBarishav  The code is not intended to be compilable code.  I don't know if a `List<String>` structure exists in java per se.  It's supposed to represent a `String[]` or an `ArrayList` of `String` or a linked list of string, or whatever kind of list structure that you feel like using

Comment: How would this program will get to the "b" in "abc"? if it will take the "a" first so will be left only "bc" and will than take "b" off and than will return  "c",and "bc"?

Comment: @DavidBarishav To understand the recursion, it's important to be able to abstract out your recursive calls.  Just trust that `GetSubwords(smallString)` will work correctly and that it will return a list of `["b", "c", "bc"]` Don't think about how it gets that list so much.  Just focus on using that list to get `["b", "c", "bc", "ab", "ac", "abc"]`

Comment: @DavidBarishav The one thing that you **do** need to think about a little is the **base case**.  That's the part at the top where you just `return str` if the string has only 1 character.

Comment: @DavidBarishav Ah, I see what you mean.  I've fixed that

Comment: I think i got it i will try to write code for it now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69343/discussion-between-david-barishav-and-sam-i-am).

Comment: Although this is a very nice answer, I think it defeats the purpose of teaching the basics of Java (I am under the impression that the OP is a beginner, and would like a beginner's answer).

Comment: @Barranka The Idea wasn't to teach the OP java,  It was to teach the OP recursion.  in fact, this answer is more c#-ish than java.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial python version of the recursion, translation in java will probably be verbose, but quite simple:

```
def subs(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return ['']
    return [pref + sb for sb in subs(s[1:]) for pref in ('', s[0])]

print subs('ABC')
```

Comment: In Haskell, there is even a builtin: [`subsequences`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm. Say string has length `n`. Generate all numbers from `0` to `2^n-1`. For every such number, scan its binary representation from left to right and write ith character to output if ith bit is set to 1.

Here is C++ example which you can translate to java:

```
char s[] = "abc";
for(int i = 0; i < 1 << 3; i++)
{   for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {   if((1 << j) & i)
            printf("%c", s[j]);
    }
    puts("");
}
```